# Ritiring old logs without using Elasticsearch-curator

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I'm running an ELK stack and would like a strategy for automatically retiring logs older than a certain age... I have tried using elasticsearch-curator but it requires python 2.7 and I have python 2.6.6, and am anxious to upgrade python in case I break other packages.

Is there a similar product or does the elasticsearch api cater for such a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of curator will work with older versions of ElasticSearch ( I'm using curator version 3.1.0 with a 1.7.1 ES cluster.)

Answer (score 0):

We started out using the Elasticsearch S3 archiving plugin but soon discovered certain limitations when wanting to restore data. We also experienced performance issues with the plugin, which tended to slow down the entire cluster. Since then, we have migrated to a new system in which we archive the data for us and our customers using our own code before indexing the data to Elasticsearch in a clear text format. This gives us all the flexibility we and our customers require.

Answer (score 0):

You may be mistaking the dependency on a given version of the elasticsearch-py module for a version of Elasticsearch. Curator version 3.5.1 requires es-py 2.3, but works with any version of elasticsearch greater than 1.0.

Comment: I should also note that Curator does _not_ require python 2.7.  It has been tested on Python version 2.6, as this is what RHEL/CentOS 6 requires.